# jQuery: select element preselect option fail

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

In [this simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63wm1r01/3/) I tested to select an option from the select element by jQuery, which does work, once... But if I want to clear preselection and set it again, for multiple times (use both buttons a second time), it doesn't change anymore... I tried it in firefox and chrome.

Why this? Haven't found a solution yet:(

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<button id="select2">preselect 2nd</button>
<button id="selectNone">preselect none</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#select2").click(function() {
    $("select option:nth-of-type(2)").attr("selected", true);
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
    $("option").attr("selected", false);
});
```

Thanks in advance!
Severin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `selected` **attribute** doesn't work because the `selected` attribute isn't the current selected state of an option; it's the *default* selected state of an option.

Just use `val`, with the `options` pseudo-array in the first case:

```
$("#select2").click(function() {
  var select = $("select");
  select.val(select[0].options[2].value);
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
  $("select").val(null);
});
```

```js
$("#select2").click(function() {
  var select = $("select");
  select.val(select[0].options[2].value);
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
  $("select").val(null);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<button id="select2">preselect 2nd</button>
<button id="selectNone">preselect none</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or alternately, using the `selected` *property* on the option:

```
$("#select2").click(function() {
  $("select option:nth-of-type(2)").prop("selected", true);
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
  $("select").val(null);
});
```

```js
$("#select2").click(function() {
  $("select option:nth-of-type(2)").prop("selected", true);
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
  $("select").val(null);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<button id="select2">preselect 2nd</button>
<button id="selectNone">preselect none</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user3375391: No worries. I just fixed a copy-and-paste error on the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code in the fiddle a bit.

```
var select = $("select");
// for instance set an ID for more than one selectboxes
var option = select.find("option");

$("#select2").click(function() {
  option.eq(1).attr("selected",true);
  select.val(option.eq(1).val()).change();
});

$("#selectNone").click(function() {
  option.attr("selected",false);
  select.change();
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/63wm1r01/23/

The most important is the `select.change();` part. It worked for me in other projects very fine.

Hope this helps.